# Azure moving resources is running for around 4 hours for a single resource

Tags: azure, resources, subscription, between, azure-resource-group

I am trying to move a virtualnetwork from one resource group to another resource and azure kept saying its moving the resource for the past 12 hours. The virtualnetwork is empty and does not have resources attached to it. why is it taking time ? How to recover from this ?
Due to that, I am not able to create or edit any of the resources now in our resource group.

Comment: Please open a support request. Azure support team should be able to help you.